# button overlaps with text

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I have placed a button in my page. But when I make it to small screen then the button overlaps with the text (see picute).

This is my code for button:

```html
   <div class="row featurette" id="v1">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">Title. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
            <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis
                euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus,
                tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="btn1">mehr Erfahren</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="500x500"
                src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/amo0f.png" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: overlaps]

Comment: The button isn't overlapping the text in the picture. What is the problem?

Comment: it doesn't look nice if I go small screen.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of it on a smaller screen and also include the css for the button.

Comment: the screenshot for smaller screen is above where I posted the question. I see that I don't have any css for the button

Comment: The button looks fine in the screenshot. Please clarify your problem.

Comment: By overlapping do you mean the edges are touching?

Comment: yes, I mean the edges are touching, sry!

Comment: you can apply `margin-bottom` to the button or `margin-top` to the image.

Comment: Try adding <br> where the space is needed.

Comment: By you classnames it looks like you're using Bootstrap? Take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Yes I am using Bootstrap

Comment: @Behar yes then take a look at the spacing documentation I posted. You can add classes `.mb-1` up to 5 or `.mt-1` to the button or image respectively. If you're only concerned with mobile you can do things such as `.mb-xs-3` or whichever fits.

Comment: thx guys, it helped!

Comment: @jerrylow thx a lot it helped!